# Split one pandas dataframe column into several so that they are binary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, binary, multiple-columns

I have a problem and would like to split a column of a pandas dataframe into several columns, where, however, only binary numbers are written (0 or 1), so that I can continue working with them. The problem is as follows ( very simplified):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 
                   'c2': [0, "A", "B", "A, B", "B", "C"]}, 
                  columns=['c1', 'c2'])
```

However, I cannot work with the second column in this way and would therefore like to divide c2 into several columns so that there are the following columns: c2_A, c2_B and c2_C. If, for example, the second column contains "A", then column c2_A should contain a 1 and otherwise a 0. If, for example, as in the fourth column, "A,B" is written, then there should be a 1 in both c2_A and c2_B and a 0 in c2_C.

I have already tried a lot and tried it with if/ else, for example, but then failed at the latest when there is more than one letter in a row (e.g. "A,B").

It would be great if someone could help me, because I'm really running out of ideas.

PS: I am also rather a Python newbie.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a zero in the first row of column `'c2'`.  How should that be handled?

Comment: If there is a 0, then there should be a 0 in each column (c2_A, c2_B,...).

Comment: So like this: `df[['c1']].join(df['c2'].replace(0, '').str.replace(' ', '').str.get_dummies(',').add_prefix('c2_'))`